# Ruby script hangs forever

Tags: ruby

This little script is supposed to generate a user-specified amount of random numbers and print them. It's a multithreaded script and I think that's where my trouble lies. I'm not getting any errors, but when run the script just hangs.

```
num = []

while 0.upto ARGV[0].to_i do
  num << rand{254}
end

current_index = 0

while current_index < num.size

chunk = num[current_index, 5]
threads = []

chunk.each do |n|
  threads << Thread.new do
    puts n
  end
end

threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end

current_index += chunk.size
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should avoid variables names that are the same as the name of one of Ruby's built-in methods. Maybe you are not familiar with the method [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `while` loop with `upto`.

Change it to:

```
0.upto ARGV[0].to_i do
  num << rand(254)
end
```

And it works properly (I've changed braces to curly one, because I believe you want 254 to be parameter here).

---

Sidenote:

Remember when writing threads program in Ruby, that CRuby has GIL - Global Interpreter Lock. Therefore only one thread will be operating at one time. If you want different behaviour - switch for example to jRuby. More information about GIL can be found f.e. here: http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil

Comment: There is no reason that `while` cannot be used with `upto`, but there may not be a good reason for doing so. Here `0.upto ARGV[0].to_i do; num << rand{254}; end` returns `0`, so we are left with `while 0...end` which is the same as `while true...end`. One could break from that loop, but that is not done here. Yes, `while` should be deleted, but don't forget to remove the final `end` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`upto` returns `self`, which is a number. Everything which isn't `false` or `nil` is trueish in Ruby, including numbers. So, you have a `while` loop whose condition is always trueish, ergo, will never stop.